# How to check if image file inputed or not in PHP?

Tags: php, html, image

I have one input field in edit.PHP as

```
<form  method='POST' action='update.PHP'>
    <input type='file' name="image" id="image">
</form>
```

Now in update.PHP I want to check if image file exist how do I check that? The script I wrote is something like this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){

    #then execute this code when there is image uploaded
}else{
    #execute this
}
```

But this script doesn't work... it return true every time whether image is added or not .... how do I prevent executing the code when image isn't there?

Here is the complete PHP script if it helps anyone to solve my problem

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image'])){
  if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
    $ff_ext = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
    $file_ext=strtolower(end($ff_ext));

    $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
    $id=md5(uniqid());

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        $filename = $id."/".$file_name;
        ////IF DIRECTORY NOT EXISTS CREATE ONE
        if(!file_exists("images/".$id)){
            if(!mkdir("images/".$id,0755,true)){
                    $error = error_get_last();
                        echo $error['message'];
                            echo 'failed';
                }
            }

        $filename = $id."/".$file_name;
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$filename);
        $dirn = "images/".$filename;
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
 }else{
    $dirn = $user['profile_pic']; //link of the existing profile picture       address 
   }
```

PS: THERE IS NO ISSUE WITH THE HTML PART.

Comment: if(!empty($_FILES['profile_image']['name'])){

    #then execute this code when there is image uploaded
}else{
    #execute this
}

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp  refer it. i think it sholud be useful to you.

Comment: also dont forget to use enctype . example - <form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: there is no problem with the html part... my problem is with the php script it is not validating if there any image uploaded or not

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: On StackOverflow we don't mark question as solved by changing it's title. Qestion will apear as open unanswered until you mark (accept) one answer as the best for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this part of your PHP code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['profile_image'])){

    #then execute this code when there is image uploaded
}else{
    #execute this
}
```

with this

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES ['profile_image'] ['tmp_name'])) {
    #then execute this code when there is image uploaded
} else {
    #execute this
}
```

And this part of your HTML code

```
<form  method='POST' action='update.PHP'>
```

with this

```
<form  method='POST' action='update.PHP' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the form tag

```
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: inorder to upload a file, you have to include enctype

Comment: @AjitDas You have a problem with uploading files. Look how many people tell you to use a `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Please open for example the link that Jees K Denny provide you in comment for your question and read why u need to use it.